# Do we need to upload new build if we just have to change iTunes App Icon?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, app-store, app-store-connect

I wanted to change the app icon (512 x 512 pixels) thru iTunes Connect.

But when I do "Edit" it does not allow me to change the icon.

So, do we have to create new version of the app in iTunes and submit it to Apple for Review?

If not, what is the way to change the AppStore icon?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The application icon is part of the bundle, and must be redeployed as an update.

Comment: OK. So I have to resubmit the app as update. Will do it. Thanks Yann for your help :)